# combinations of a strange magic square

Tags: mathematics, combinatorics, magic-square

The following question has been described to me by my math teacher:

> The diagram below is to be filled in so that each white square contains a different whole number from 1 to 12 (inclusive) and the four numbers in the squares along each edge have the same total.
>
> [image: magic_square]

The question is:

> In how many different ways can this be done correctly???

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's start by filling out the gaps in the grid with letters to make it easier to describe:

```
.----.---.---.---.
| 5  | y | 3 | x |
:----+---+---+---:
| a  |   |   | c |
:----+---+---+---:
| b  |   |   | d |
:----+---+---+---:
| 12 | p | q | 6 |
'----'---'---'---'
```

> The sum of all the numbers in the grid must be `4n - (5 + 6 + 12 + x)`, where `n` is the sum of each edge, and x is the missing corner
>  number. This is because the numbers in the corners are counted twice
>  each when summing the edges. As we know the grid is filled by the
>  numbers 1 to 12 inclusive, we know that this is equal to 78: `78 = 4n - (5 + 6 + 12 + x)`.

> We now need to find `x`. Rearranging, we get `78 + (5 + 6 + 12 + x) = 4n`, so `101 + x` must be divisible by 4. As `3` has already been used
>  in the grid, we are left with the possibilities of `7` or `11`.

> If `x = 7`, `n = 27`, so `y` in our diagram must be equal to 8.
>  Looking now at the left column, the only remaining pair of numbers
>  that sum to `10` for `a` and `b` are `1` and `9`. Moving to the right
>  column, `c` and `d` need to sum to 14. The only pair of numbers that
>  fulfils this requirement is `4` and `10`. Finally, looking at `p` and
>  `q` on the bottom row, we need these two numbers to sum to 9, however
>  the only numbers remaining are `2` and `11`. We can therefore exclude
>  the possibility that `x = 7`.

> We now know that `x` must equal `11`. This means that `n = 28`, so `y = 9`. Looking at the bottom row, we need `p + q = 10`. The only free pair of numbers which fulfils this is `2` and `8`. Moving on to the
>  left-hand column, we require `a + b = 11`. The remaining possibilities
>  are `1` and `10`, or `4` and `7`. Finally, we look at the right-hand
>  column - we again need `c + d = 11`. The only solution remaining is
>  the pair of numbers that weren't used to fill `a` and `b`.

> The number of correct solutions, therefore, assuming we fill the numbers in in
>  that order, is the number of choices for `p`, multiplied by the number
>  of choices for `a`, multiplied by the number of choices for `c`. This
>  is equal to `2 x 4 x 2 = 16`.